# "certificate signed by unknown authority" while trying to pull docker image from trusted registry

Tags: ssl, docker, debian, docker-trusted-registry

I am trying to pull a docker image from a Docker Trusted Registry. I know the https certificate is invalid and want to bypass it for now because I am just testing something quick.

I'm on

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l
```

and start docker by `sudo service docker restart`

I've added the line below to `/etc/init.d/docker` and have restarted docker after making the change but it isn't helping.

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry ipaddress.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```

I keep seeing this error while trying to pull

> Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://ipaddress.compute-1.amazonaws.com/v1/_ping: x509:
>   certificate signed by unknown authority

My docker version is Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638

Answer (score 1):

If your registry is trusted, then you must have certifications. Add `--insecure-registry` can not help you bypass the certification validation.

If you can bypass a certification validation simply by adding a parameter to Docker daemon configuration, then the trusted registry is meaningless :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also add the certificate of the remote docker registry to `/etc/docker/certs.d/<docker registry>/registry.crt` on your host system and you should be fine. This should work without a restart of the docker daemon.